# list view position in on touch even returning 0 always

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event

Following is my code:
but i am getting 0 value for pos.
please help

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                pos = listView.pointToPosition((int) motionEvent.getX(), (int) motionEvent.getY());
                view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                return true;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make changes as per shown in following app

```
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder;
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motion)
       if (motionEvent.getAction() == Motion.ACTION_DOWN) {
             shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
             pos = listView.pointToPosition((int) motion.getX(), (int) motion.getY());
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pos is:"+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
             return false;
       }
}
```